# Как заменить ссылки на картинки на атрибут <img>

Tags: img, изображения

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь все ссылки на картинки с страницы изменить на встроенное в сайт фото методом замены элемента `<a>` на `<img>` — но никак не получается

Пожалуйста помогите, можно jQuery или javascript — главное чтоб работало

у меня такие ссылки, пример из моего задания:

```html
<a href="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/2017/03/19/2245758/tn/02-funny-cat-wallpapercat-wallpaper.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/2017/03/19/2245758/tn/02-funny-cat-wallpapercat-wallpaper.jpg</a>
```

должно стать так:

```html
    <img src="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/2017/03/19/2245758/tn/02-funny-cat-wallpapercat-wallpaper.jpg">
```

Нашел пример, но он неполноценный — логика правильная, но не ищет ссылки:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

 if(url.search('.jpg') != -1 || url.search('.png') != -1 || url.search('.gif') != -1){
                 
                return "<img src=\"" + url + "\" >";  };

 });
```

Спасибо и дай Бог здоровья тому кто поможет

Comment: да  кстати через html прошу не предлагать, все ссылки постят пользователи, нужно через js
и чтобы скрипт не путал ссылки на картинки с обычными ссылками

Answer (score 2):

- получаем все ссылки методом [`document.getElementsByTagName('a')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)
- обрабатываем каждую из них циклом [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- проверяем, если это ссылка на картинку ([`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`.endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)), то

  - создаём элемент картинки [`document.createElement('img')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement)
  - присваиваем свойствам [`src` и `alt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) нужные значение
  - заменяем ссылку только что созданной картинкой —
    [`.replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

```js
for (let link of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) {
  let isLinkImage = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'].some(extension => link.href.endsWith(extension));
  if (isLinkImage) {
    let image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = link.href;
    image.alt = 'TODO: придумать нормальный alt';
    link.replaceWith(image);
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 20vw;
  max-height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<h3>ссылка, которая будет заменена:</h2>
<a href="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/2017/03/19/2245758/tn/02-funny-cat-wallpapercat-wallpaper.jpg">ссылка</a>
<h3>обычная ссылка:</h2>
<a href="https://ya.ru">ссылка</a>
<h3>обычная картинка:</h2>
<img src="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/2017/03/19/2245758/tn/02-funny-cat-wallpapercat-wallpaper.jpg" alt="картинка, не будет изменена">
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!